# Why can @StateObject be used with a synthesized init but not if you write it out?

Tags: swift, swiftui, combine

Playing around with `SwiftUI` and state management and ran into a strange thing. Why does this code compile:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: MyViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $viewModel.myProperty)
    }
}
```

But not this:

```
struct MyView: View {
    @StateObject var viewModel: MyViewModel
    
    init() {
        viewModel = MyViewModel() // same issue if i pass it in as a param
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        TextField("", text: $viewModel.myProperty)
    }
}
```

In the first example, the `init()` is synthezised so it's still there, and can and is used from an external view initializing `MyView`. In the second example I just explicitly write out the `init()` but now I get the error `Cannot assign to property: 'viewModel' is a get-only property`.

And, yes, I know that `@StateObject` properties should be initialized inside its view as it's owned by the view. But I'm just trying to grasp these weird cases that keeps popping up with state management.

Comment: In SwiftUI the View struct is the view model already so you don't need a StateObject for that. StateObject is for an async Combine pipeline (which you don't even need anymore since we have the async/await `.task` modifier).

Answer (score 4):

> Declare state objects as private to prevent setting them from a memberwise initializer, which can conflict with the storage management that SwiftUI provides

```
init(name: String) {
    // SwiftUI ensures that the following initialization uses the
    // closure only once during the lifetime of the view, so
    // later changes to the view's name input have no effect.
    _model = StateObject(wrappedValue: DataModel(name: name))
}
```

> Even for a configurable state object, you still declare it as private. This ensures that you can’t accidentally set the parameter through a memberwise initializer of the view, because doing so can conflict with the framework’s storage management and produce unexpected results.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/stateobject